# When to use 'divisible' vs 'dividable'

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I realised today that I use the terms *divisible* and *dividable* interchangeably, even though there may be a difference between them.

If they are in fact different, I'm interested in any general rule that might apply to a large case of similarly related terms as well.

Comment: Garner defines "dividable" as a NEEDLESS variant of "divisible".

Comment: @Carlo_R., so there's no semantic difference at all?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference at all.

Comment: Besides *divisible/dividable*, other such pairs include: *admissible/admittable, corrosible/corrodable, defensible/defendable,
derisible/deridable, discussible/discutable, divisible/dividable,
evasible/evadable, expansible/expandable, explosible/explodable,
invasible/invadable, offensible/offendable, persuasible/persuadable,
protrusible/protrudable, remissible/remittable,
reprehensible/reprehendable, transmissible/transmittable.* Beyond those, you also have such things as *dissoluble/dissolvable*.

Comment: @tchrist, two quibbles: *[discutable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discutable)* is French but not English;  *[offensible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offensible)* (“(obsolete) That may give offense”) is not parallel to  *[offendable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offendable)* (“Capable of being offended”).

Comment: @jwpat7 They may be rare, but both exist in a comparable sense. OED ***discutable***: “Capable of being discussed; **discussible.”** with citation “1893 *Sat. Rev.* 11 Feb. 150/1 ― Many insoluble or discutable points.” OED ***offensible***: “Liable to take offence, easily offended.” with citation “18·· Mrs. Browning *Lett. R. H. Horne* (1877) I. xxix. 192 ― From my own proper consciousness of offensible self-love.”

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In common usage there may be little or no difference in meaning; but in mathematical writing, *divisible* has an  accepted usage not held by *dividable*.  Oxford Dictionary gives  “Mathematics (of a number) containing another number a number of times without a remainder: 24 is divisible by 4” as sense 2 of *[divisible](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/divisible?q=divisible)*.  [Sometimes](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evenly+divisible%2Cevenly+dividable&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) redundant wording like *evenly divisible* is used, and I suppose  *evenly dividable* could be used, but it isn't.

I don't know of a general rule.  Incidentally, as seen via links in [google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dividable%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en), *dividable* is a word respectable enough to use, in spite of suffering some disrespect, as [in following](http://books.google.com/books?id=_UD_dEpC0qwC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=%22dividable%22&source=bl&ots=MK6MXdCzQN&sig=PQxa5pph5ZEGGJmbeJS4gNiuMAw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AQ5zUJ-ZO8T2iwLo8oGQAw&ved=0CF4Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22dividable%22&f=false):
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Use *dividable* only if you want to appear strange... GoogleFight:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually both are correct, the difference is the origin of the word. Divisible comes from the Latin root of certain words in English, it is the same word in French; while dividable comes from the Germanic root of English.

The same can be applied to various words in the English language, those that find their roots from Latin are generally employed by higher classes of English society such as scientific terms, while its Germanic counter-part are mostly used in its popular usage.